# Listing interfaces in interfaces in Go

Tags: interface, go

I don't understand the following code snippet in the `container/heap` package.

```
type Interface interface {
    sort.Interface   //Is this line a method?
    Push(x interface{})
    Pop() interface{}
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a type declaration.

The `heap.Interface` interface embeds the `sort.Interface` interface.

You can see it as a kind of inheritance/specialization : it means that the structs implementing the `heap.Interface` interface are defined as the ones that implement the `sort.Interface` methods and the `Push` and `Pop` methods.

Interface embeding is described in Effective Go : http://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#embedding